# configure jndi.xml in serviceMix to work with MQseries

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, jndi, apache-servicemix

My j2EE app is currently running on **ServiceMix**. Now i want to add JMS to my app. The application should able to send/receive the JMS message to/from  the queue that stays on **MQSeries**.

```
mq.hostname=10.3.6.19
mq.channel=CHANNEL
mq.queueManager=QManager
mq.port=1422
```

What i would like to do is:

```
 1. Create a jndi.xml file and do configuration for jms stuff.
 2. my app will initialize the context, look up jndi name, and create a connection, queueManager, queue. .etc
 3. Develop send and receive methods.
```

> My question is: 
>            Can you tell me how to do 1st and 2nd steps. 
>           (the script inside ServiceMix's jndi is diffrent with tomcat's
>   jndi and others.
>           ServiceMix using Spring based JNDI provider.
>       http://servicemix.apache.org/jndi-configuration.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into something similar with Weblogic.  The following link uses spring-dm to integrate with websphere.  It also takes it to the next logical step and adds camel to the mix.
http://lowry-techie.blogspot.com/2010/11/camel-integration-with-websphere-mq.html

Without using Spring-dm, you may run into classloader issues when trying to load the InitialContextFactory from the websphere jar (this is an issue I had with the Weblogic jar)